# Proper way to build Django form/class method

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a Django form (Django non-rel v1.5.5) with a form/class method that works fine. However, now I've moved on to building unit tests for the application I have a problem testing a form/class method. I assume the form/class method is defined improperly.

## forms.py

```
class TimeForm(forms.Form):
    def build_choices(start, stop, incr=1):
        # Form/class method that builds a list of tuples of identical i, i values for forms.ChoiceField
        choice_list = []
        temp_list   = [i for i in range(start, stop, incr)]

        for i in temp_list:
            choice_list.append(('%02d' % i, '%02d' % i))

        return choice_list

    hour_choices   = build_choices(1, 13) # E.g., [('01', '01'), ('02', '02') ... ]
    minute_choices = build_choices(0, 60, 15)
    hour     = forms.ChoiceField(choices=hour_choices)
    minute   = forms.ChoiceField(choices=minute_choices)
```

The above code generates forms fine, with the proper choices for the form fields. However, when I try to unit test the `build_choices` method, I hit a wall.

## some tests

```
"""Testing the build_choices method."""
> form = TimeForm()
> form.build_choices(1, 10) # This will not work.
> *** TypeError: range() integer start argument expected, got TimeForm.
>
> TimeForm.build_choices(1, 10) # This will not work.
> *** TypeError: unbound method build_choices() must be called with TimeForm instance as first argument (got int instance instead)
>
> TimeForm.build_choices(form, 1, 10)
> *** TypeError: range() integer start argument expected, got TimeForm.
```

However,

```
> TimeForm.hour_choices
> [('01', '01'), ('02', '02') ... ]
```

Is there a better way/proper way to define a form method that isn't an instance method? E.g., `TimeForm(self, start, end, inc)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the same as Tomita, it looks like before initialization of the class, `build_choices` is a function, and after it, it is an instance method. I think another option, instead of putting `build_choices` outside of the class is:

```
class TimeForm(forms.Form):
    def build_choices(self, start, stop, incr=1):
        # Form/class method that builds a list of tuples of identical i, i values for forms.ChoiceField
        choice_list = []
        temp_list   = [i for i in range(start, stop, incr)]

        for i in temp_list:
            choice_list.append(('%02d' % i, '%02d' % i))

        return choice_list

    hour_choices   = build_choices(None, 1, 13) # E.g., [('01', '01'), ('02', '02') ... ]
    minute_choices = build_choices(None, 0, 60, 15)
    hour     = forms.ChoiceField(choices=hour_choices)
    minute   = forms.ChoiceField(choices=minute_choices)
```

In this case (like in your example) in the tests you will not be able to call `build_choices` as a class method (for that you would need to use the decorator @classmethod or @staticmethod but if you do you will not be able to call it from the class attributes).

You could call it on he tests like this:

```
form = TimeForm()
form.build_choices(1, 10)
TimeForm.build_choices(TimeForm(), 1, 10)
TimeForm.build_choices(form, 1, 10)
```

Comment: This is _exactly_ what I was looking for and very educational. I didn't realize I could pass in `None` where an instance was required by `self`. Further, good info on the method decorators, may come in handy in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is some weird setup. You have a class method that's immediately invoked as a normal function until the class finishes initializing.

I'm not a deep python wizard, but it appears functions are converted to  class methods only after class setup.

Bottom line: `TimeForm.build_choices` is a class method. Its first argument is always the class instance.

Solution:

Define `build_choices` outside the class.

Test the function object itself via `TimeForm.hour_choices.__func__(1, 10)`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but it appears that the private method `__func__` does not exist on those class attributes. Possible that it is version specific.

Comment: @TechMedicNYC whoops, if you're using python 2 it's `im_func`. `__func__` is the standardized 3+ version, which is also in 2.7